# Passing bash variable to awk

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to extract a row/column element from a text table using awk within a function in bash.  Specifically:

```
getel() {
    awk -v col=$3 'FNR==$2 {print $col }' $1
}
```

The usage is:

```
getel <file> <row> <col>
```

If I type in:

```
awk -v col=2 'FNR==1 {print $col}' infile
```

at the bash prompt, I get row 1 col 2 as expected.
I dug through the various bash-awk questions but none seemed to get me to a solution.

Ultimately,  I want to assign the result to another bash variable, ie:

```
FOUND=`awk -v col=2 'FNR==1 {print $col}' infile`
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass another command line variable to awk:

```
getel() {
    awk -v row=$2 -v col=$3 'NR==row {print $col }' $1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use bash variables directly:

```
awk 'NR=='$2'{print $'$3'}' $1
```